# I need to make a generator function that takes *args as an input

Tags: python, python-3.x, args

I need to make a function which will return successively as a generator,
the square of the difference of each value from the average of all the values given as input.

The function must

A) accept an undefined number of parameters

B) be a generator function

The values will be integers.

To calculate the average of all values I can import statistics.

Have you got any idea?

The code I tried to write:

```
import statistics
def squares(*args):
    for i in args:
        a=(args-av)**2
        yield a
lst=[]
count = int(input("Give the amount of numbers: "))
for i in range (0,count):
    ele=int(input())
    lst.append(ele)
av=statistics.mean(lst)
for i in squares(*lst):
    print(i)
```

Answer (score 2):

The only error in your script comes from using `args` instead of `i` in your calculations:

```
import statistics
def squares(*args):
    for i in args:
        a=(i-av)**2 # <-- There.
        yield a
lst=[]
count = int(input("Give the amount of numbers: "))
for i in range (0,count):
    ele=int(input())
    lst.append(ele)
av=statistics.mean(lst)
for i in squares(*lst):
    print(i)
```

I would also advise using `def squares(av, *args)` just so that your `av` does not come out of somewhere. You then have to modify your last but one line to `for i in squares(av, *lst)`. Otherwise everything looks ok!

My suggestion:

```
import statistics

def squares(average, *items):
    for item in items:
        yield (item - average)**2

lst = []
count = int(input("Give the amount of numbers: "))
for _ in range(count):
    item = int(input())
    lst.append(item)

average = statistics.mean(lst)
for square in squares(average, *lst):
    print(square)
```

Answer (score 1):

Your `av` variable should be computed inside the generator function:

```
def squares(*args):
    av = sum(args)/len(args)
    for a in args:
        yield (a-av)**2
```

Comment: I don't think `//` is appropriate for an average calculation. The questioner's code uses `statistics.mean` which returns a float if necessary. Otherwise this is probably what is wanted, since you're doing the average inside the generator.

Comment: That was my bad (accidental double tap on / I guess)